# Navigation Drawer Home Button Behavior

Tags: android, navigation-drawer, material-design

Does anyone know if there is any documentation on the behaviour of list items inside navigation drawers on android?

For example the photos app, when you select Photos, Assistant or Collection, the navigation drawer icon (hamburger) stays in the top left of the action bar.

However, when you select Shared albums, Device folders, Trash, Settings or Help & feedback, there is a back arrow on the top left of the action bar.

Is there documentation that defines when to have the navigation drawer icon (hamburger) or the back arrow?

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

> Navigation Drawer Design
>   Before you decide to use a navigation drawer in your app, you should understand the use cases and design principles defined in the Navigation Drawer design guide.

http://developer.android.com/intl/es/training/implementing-navigation/nav-drawer.html

Answer (score 0):

You must checkout design patterns for android navigation drawer. Also go through different apps and check out when, which button is used.

*Hamburger icon* button usually indicates that there is a slide menu. Tap it to show/hide list of items, and user will be redirected to some other screen/ fragment.

*Back button* is preferred when you want to **navigate back** to some previous screen/ fragment.

Comment: This does not answer the question at all. The question is why for some menu entries the hamburger button stays and for some a back button is shown instead.

For example, in Google Play, in the menu choosing My account, you'll still see the hamburger button, but when you press Settings, there's a back button instead.